# Configure the administrative account

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone

I'm deploying openstack- stein version on ubuntu pro 18.04 LTS.

I come across these lines when configuring keystone - identity service, as of this [article](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/stein/install/keystone-install-ubuntu.html).

Would anybody please explain how to set this following configuration:

```
$ export OS_USERNAME=admin
$ export OS_PASSWORD=ADMIN_PASS
$ export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
$ export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
$ export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
$ export OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller:5000/v3
$ export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
```

If I'm already in root mode, is there any need to these env variables ?

---

**If the question helped, up-vote it.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you are root or not has no meaning for the `openstack` command. The OpenStack admin user has nothing to do with the Linux root user.

You don't need the variables, but your command line becomes very long without them, for example `openstack --os-username=admin --os-password=ADMIN_PASS --os-project-name=admin --os-user-domain-name=Default --os-project-domain-name=Default --os-auth-url=http://controller:5000/v3 --os-identity-api-version=3 server list`. These variables are the most convenient way to tell the `openstack` command under which identity it should perform its actions.

How to set them? Type them on the command line, but the most common method is [putting them in a file that you source](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/stein/install/keystone-openrc-ubuntu.html). You can then have several such files for several different identities, such as the `admin` and `demo` identities in the linked document, which allows you to quickly switch from one identity to the other.

Answer (score 1):

In short, put those commands in `admin-openrc.sh`, then `source admin-openrc.sh` when you need to use openstack-cli with administrative account.